# Upgrading 8 speed shimano Acera RD-M3000 to 11 speed Deore XT M-8000?

Tags: mountain-bike, cassette

I want to upgrade my existing setup, but i wanted to know if the frame will have enough space to make it possible ?

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: it would be good to add what you are trying to accomplish - wider range, crisper shifting, etc. rather than exactly what you would like to do

Comment: Its your money, but I would hesitate to upgrade Acera 8speed to XT 11 speed.  You will probably spend more than the bike is worth on the drive train, but still have Acera quality wheels, hubs, BB, cranks, forks, bars, brakes and frame.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as long as your bike has normal 135mm spacing, there's no obstacle with frame spacing or other frame compatibility. Despite the addition of new rear end/spacing standards, compatibility with standard 135 QR frames hasn't been dropped.

Answer (score 0):

Most mountain bikes have 135mm rear frame spacing, so you can go from a 8 to 11 speed cassette.

<strike>Unfortunately, your 8-speed wheel hub is likely not compatible with an 11-speed cassette.</strike>  -- Note: this incompatibility may just be for road bikes.

So you'll need to get:

- <strike>a new 11-speed hub or wheel</strike>
- a new cassette
- a new derailleur
- a new shifter / brifter
- a new chain

In most cases, you're likely better off either getting a wider-spaced 8-speed cassette and keeping your rear derailleur; or, alternately changing your crankset to a triple.

[rant] Note that going from 8 to 11 isn't really an "upgrade" except in the eyes of Shimano. Especially given that the chains and cogs are thinner, for mountainbiking it might actually be considered a downgrade. [/rant]

Comment: 11 speed mountain cassettes don't need longer freehubs.

Comment: That incompatibility is just in road bikes? Thanks, editing.

Comment: Shimano Rd and SRAM rd both use wider 11 speed freehubs, SRAM MTN uses their XD driver, Shimano MTN uses standard 10sp freehub body. https://www.bikerumor.com/2012/05/01/11-speed-road-bike-hubs-versus-10-speed-tech-breakdown/

Comment: Kind of. Many SRAM 11 mountain bikes come with standard 8/9/10spd freehubs and either PG1130 or a Sunrace or other cassette. PG1130 may look small in the lineup but it's large in the number of bikes that have it. The XD driver setup pushes the price point up a little.

Comment: @nathan do you have an example of this for my own curiosity? I had only seen GX/NX/+ 1x11 (with wide range XD) or below that GX 2x10 (with 11-36 in the back)

Comment: Here's one I can think of offhand http://salsacycles.com/bikes/timberjack/2017_timberjack_29_nx1 . You'll see similar drivetrain setups on many SRAM 11 MTBs around this price range.